# Fire notification with AlarmManager

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I am using AlarmManager to fire Notification. I want that notification fires at 10:30 am of the morning and repeat at every 24 hours. I don't want notification when opening application.

I am posting my code, main problem is that It fires alarm in the nite time also at 10:30 (if phone timezone is of 12 hours). I check this code with modification yest and I got alarm yest nite at 10:30, 1, 4, 7.

Please help me solve the problem, I am trying to solve it from the long time.

Code :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Splash.this,
            0, myIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

    firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    long intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();
    long currentTime = currentCal.getTimeInMillis();

    if (intendedTime >= currentTime) {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, intendedTime,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    } else {
        firingCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, intendedTime,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
```

because this is the hour in 24hour notation.

It also seems you forget to add a day in the else statement because the if and the else do exactly the same now.

Comment: @lvo Beckers, I add a day in else statement but that time, It fired notification only next day, nt after that...

Comment: @Jeeten Are you sure it doesn't work like this? Also, are you sure you haven't shutdown your telephone in the meantime because alarms get lost after reboot. See documentation of [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)   "Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), but will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted. "

Comment: @lvo Beckers, It is working but As my company sir said, after getting alarm on its set time, it also fires after around every 20-30 minutes. So I am confused. I don't think so that any problem is with code.